# Find matches between two columns, sum 3rd column.

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula which lets me search for matches between two columns, and where a match is found, add the associated value from a 3rd column.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jfxx.png)

If a fruit in column B matches **any** of the values in Column A, add the associated value from Column C. Here you have 2 grapefruit matches ($2) and 2 orange matches ($.5) so you get $5.

Is there a formula to do this automatically? Huge thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple version is

```
=sum(filter(C2:C8, match(B2:B8, A2:A4, 0)))
```

which looks up each element of B2:B8 in the range A2:A4, and if there is a match, includes the corresponding entry from C in the sum.

If you expect the entries in column A to grow (so they won't always stay A2:A4), the following may be preferable:

```
=sum(filter(C2:C8, match(B2:B8, filter(A2:A, len(A2:A)), 0)))
```

Here the fixed range A2:A4 is replaced by the output of a filter, which returns all nonempty cell in A2:A.